# Sanitize-html.js remove comment ex <!--[if !supportLists]-->

Tags: redactor, html-sanitizing

I am using [`sanitize-html.js`](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) and Redactor editor, version 10.1.0.

I copy content from a Word document and before paste it into redactor I clean up the HTML with `sanitize-html.js`.

The problem is that `sanitize-html.js` removes MS word comments like `<!--[if !supportLists]-->` so Redactor is not able to generate `<ul>` and `<li>` without the above comment.

Comment: Instead of replacing `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` you can use backticks (`\``) to mark them as code.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris I will use it next time whenever need